# An optimal triangle

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, optimization, lebesgue-measure

Let $D = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ be the unit square in the plane.

Let $\mathcal{T}_d$ be the set of all non-degenerate triangles in the plane with at least one vertex at distance $d > 0$ from $D$ (the distance of a point from $D$ is defined to be its distance from any point in $D$ closest to it).

For any triangle $T$ in $\mathcal{T}_d$ let $p(T)$ denote the proportion of its area outside $D$, i.e, $p(T) = \dfrac{\mu(T\setminus D)}{ \mu(T)}$ where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Let $c(d) := \inf_{T \in \mathcal{T}_d} p(T).$

1. Is $c(d) > 0 ?$
2. Is there an expression for $c(d)$ in terms of $d$ or a strictly positive lower bound?

My conjecture is that $c(d) = \left(\frac{d}{1+d}\right)^2$ and this bound is attained by a triangle one of whose vertices lies at a distance $d$ directly above midpoint of a side of $D$, and its other two vertices are the endpoints of the opposite side.

[Added later]
My conjecture is wrong,"Intelligenti pauca" has shown in the comments that $c(d) \leq \left(\frac{d}{\sqrt{2}+d}\right)^2 < \left(\frac{d}{1+d}\right)^2.$

Comment: Taking a vertex of $T$ at $(1+d/\sqrt2,1+d/\sqrt2)$ and the other two at $(\epsilon,0)$ and $(0,\epsilon)$ then $\inf p(T)=d^2/(\sqrt2+d)^2$, which is lower than your result.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Updated the question.